# Is Histacom available on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I was wondering if Histacom can be installed on Ubuntu. And if it can instructions would be appreciated. I've only found a megaupload link (which prove to be quite useless these days).

Comment: Where is the official website? I have not heard of this software before, and Google isn't helping me.

Comment: This is all I've found http://game-hackers.com/threads/3164-Histacom-Ultra-Realistic-Hacking-Game

Comment: Where is the download link? How would I install it if I were on Windows? It seems to be a program without a parent.

Answer (score 1):

Download from any of the following links (multiple links in case links go down): 
http://bayfiles.com/file/BPXv/rVFA3K/Histacom_1.8.5.zip

http://d01.megashares.com/index.php?d01=afhPyjc

http://www.crocko.com/DA0BB5669485476CAF0C103F5DCE3CFF/Histacom_1.8.5.zip

This game may work on Wine with Ubuntu but requires many dependencies. I am the original Histacom developer in case you are interested. I attempted multiple times to hand development over, but those who attempted working on it were never reliable and instead stole the source code for their own games.

Contact me at 12padams@gmail.com if you wish to have the source code. I want this game to go somewhere... Whether you play to sell it or continue developing it for a free release.

Answer (score 1):

Histacom has recently been uploaded to Indiedb and is currently the 13th most popular game there out of almost 8,000. I highly recommend downloading it off indiedb over the other links I posted because I removed the need to have 16 different dependanies installed to get the game to run. The indiedb version only requires 1 dependency which is the Microsoft .net 4.5 framework,